# sudo apt install

Tags: apt, updates, virtualbox, juju, openstack

```
$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
Get:3 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Get:5 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]
Ign:4 https://www.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian focal InRelease
Err:6 https://www.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 137.254.60.32 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Is that the correct repository url? Are you trying to install virtualbox and manually added it to your apt sources or did it suddenly break? Check out "Debian-based Linux distributions" [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads).

Answer (score 1):

The entry in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` or `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/...` is incorrect. It should be

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian focal contrib
```

The domain is `download.virtualbox.org`, not `www.virtualbox.org`.